# Rotate a document by 90 degrees before printing

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, printing, windows-runtime

I have created a sample code to print a document using C# XAML in a Windows 8 App. Now when I print I want the document to be printed 90 degrees rotated.

**How can I achieve this?**

Following is my code:

```
/// <summary>
/// PrintDocument is a Xaml object which converts some PrintManager functionality into paradigms
/// which are used in Xaml (eg. callbacks into events with event handlers).
/// </summary>
private PrintDocument printDocument = null;

/// <summary>
/// The print document source
/// </summary>
IPrintDocumentSource printDocumentSource;

/// <summary>
/// This function registers the app for printing with Windows and sets up the necessary event handlers for the print process.
/// </summary>
private void RegisterForPrinting()
{
    // Create the PrintDocument.
    printDocument = new PrintDocument();
    printDocumentSource = printDocument.DocumentSource;
    printDocument.AddPages += OnPrintDocumentAddPages;
    printDocument.GetPreviewPage += OnPrintDocumentGetPreviewPage;

    // Create a PrintManager and add a handler for printing initialization.
    PrintManager printMan = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();
    printMan.PrintTaskRequested += PrintTaskRequested;
}

/// <summary>
/// This function unregisters the app for printing with Windows.
/// </summary>
private void UnregisterForPrinting()
{
    // Set the instance of the PrintDocument to null.
    printDocument = null;

    // Remove the handler for printing initialization.
    PrintManager printMan = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();
    printMan.PrintTaskRequested -= PrintTaskRequested;
}


/// <summary>
/// This is the event handler for PrintManager.PrintTaskRequested.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">PrintManager</param>
/// <param name="e">PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs </param>
private void PrintTaskRequested(PrintManager sender, PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    PrintTask printTask = e.Request
                           .CreatePrintTask("Boarding Pass", PrintSourceTaskHandler);
}

/// <summary>
/// Prints the source task handler.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="args">The args.</param>
private void PrintSourceTaskHandler(PrintTaskSourceRequestedArgs args)
{
    args.SetSource(printDocumentSource);
}

private void OnPrintDocumentAddPages(object sender, AddPagesEventArgs e)
{

    printDocument.AddPage(root);
    printDocument.AddPagesComplete();
}

private void OnPrintDocumentGetPreviewPage(object sender, GetPreviewPageEventArgs e)
{
    printDocument.SetPreviewPage(e.PageNumber, root);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this problem I changed the default orientation of the paper to Landscape and it worked to change the print to 90 degree orientation. Following is change in the code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the event handler for PrintManager.PrintTaskRequested.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">PrintManager</param>
    /// <param name="e">PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs </param>
    private void PrintTaskRequested(PrintManager sender, PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintTask printTask = e.Request
                               .CreatePrintTask("Pass", PrintSourceTaskHandler);
        printTask.Options.Orientation = PrintOrientation.Landscape;
    }
```